# Dual Space isomorphic with all function

Tags: dual-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $\mathbb X$ be an infinite set and $k$ be a field
Define $$C_c(\mathbb X,k)=\{f\in k^\mathbb X:f(x)=0\text{ for all but finite }x's\}$$

Prove $C_c(\mathbb X,k)^*\cong k^\mathbb X$

If it were finite dimensional, it would obviously not be true due to dimensional difference.

I know $\phi \in C_c(\mathbb X,k)^*$ maps $f(\in C_c(\mathbb X,k))$ to a scaler (belonging to k?)

I don't think I have anymore clue. Please give hints. This is supposed to be homework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $C_c(\mathbb{X},k)$ is the the $k$-vector space spanned by $\{1_x: x\in X\}$.
So an element $\phi$ of the dual vector space $C_c(\mathbb{X},k)^\vee$ determines a function $f\colon\mathbb{X}\to k$, namely $x\mapsto\phi(1_x)$, and conversely any choice of function $f\colon\mathbb{X}\to k$ determines $\phi$.  Now check that this bijection is actually a $k$-linear map.

Comment: If $C_c(\mathbb X,k)$ were spanned by the set you mentioned, wouldn't it also include functions with infinite non-zeros?

Comment: No, In linear algebra, span is by definition the set of all (finite!) linear combinations.  Infinite sums don't make any sense unless there are only finitely many nonzero terms (because you don't have a topology to describe convergence of partial sums).

Comment: ok. I Think I have a good enough idea now. Thank you